# Chemistry toilet paper

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

This is a stupid question, but I can’t find one of the compounds on this toilet paper:
[image: Nice toilet paper]

I have in order:

- Salicylic acid
- Aceton
- Caffeine
- ?
- Urea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing compound is 4-[1-hydroxy-2-(methylamino)ethyl]benzene-1,2-diol, also known as [adrenaline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine).